# How to inherit of this class

Tags: python-2.7, gtk3

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: ISO-8859-1 -*-
from gi.repository import GLib, Gtk, Gio
import sys

from gi.repository import  Gdk
from gi.repository.GdkPixbuf import Pixbuf, InterpType

class MyAbout(Gtk.AboutDialog):
    __gtype_name__ = 'MyAbout' # nom pour css
    def __init__(self,title='',version="1.0",\
                 authors=["Francis"],\
                 name="PyGObject Tutorial",\
                 comment="New tutorial on using Python with GTK+ 3",\
                 website="http://www.learngtk.org/",\
                 label="LearnGTK Website",\
                 filename=None,\
                 size_x=100, size_y=100):
        Gtk.AboutDialog.__init__(self)
        self.set_title(title)
        self.set_version(version)
        self.set_authors(authors)
        if filename is not None:
            file = filename
        else:
            file = "/home/francis/Documents/Python-linux/demo_gtk2/battery.png"
        pixbuf = Pixbuf.new_from_file_at_size(file,size_x, size_y)
        self.set_logo(pixbuf)
        self.set_name(name)
        self.set_comments(comment)
        self.set_website(website)
        self.set_website_label(label)

__version__ = "V1_30"

class MyApp_root(object):
    """ just a little app with few menu """
    def __init__(self):
        GLib.set_application_name('My App')
        self.app = Gtk.Application.new('org.example.test', 0)
        self.app.connect('startup', self.on_app_startup)
        self.app.connect('activate', self.on_app_activate)
        self.app.connect('shutdown', self.on_app_shutdown)

    def add_sub_menu(self,texte, menu):
        """ just add submenu to menu return need reference to sub_menu"""
        submenu = Gio.Menu()
        menu.append_submenu(texte, submenu)
        return submenu

    def add_menu_bar(self,app):
        """ just add function menubar app need refernce to app_menu"""
        menu_bar = Gio.Menu()
        app.set_menubar(menu_bar)
        return menu_bar

    def add_section(self,app):
        """ just add a section
        note between 2 sections there is a separator"""
        section = Gio.Menu()
        app.append_section(None, section)
        return  section

    def add_simple_action(self, app, name, callback):
        """ in order to create callback fonction linked menu"""
        action = Gio.SimpleAction.new(name, None)
        action.connect('activate', callback)
        app.add_action(action)

    def add_menuitem(self,section,text,link,attribut_type=None, attribut_value=None):
        """ just add a item with parameter """
        item = Gio.MenuItem.new(text,link)
        if attribut_type is not None:
            # example item.set_attribute_value("accel", GLib.Variant("s", "<Control>Q"))
            item.set_attribute_value(attribut_type, attribut_value)
        section.append_item(item)

    def run(self, argv):
        """ in order to run class """
        self.app.run(argv)

    def on_app_startup(self, app):
        """ auto start app in window, set menu and call back
        standard design in python callback action  is action_cb"""
        self.window = Gtk.ApplicationWindow.new(app)
        self.window.set_default_size(640, 480)
        self.window.set_title('AppMenu Demo')
        app.add_window(self.window)
        # # add Appmenu to app 
        self.app_menu = Gio.Menu()
        section = self.add_section(self.app_menu)
        self.add_menuitem(section,'Quit', 'app.quit',"accel", GLib.Variant("s", "<Control>Q"))

        # it's necessary to link app-menu to app after section definition if not accelerator don't operate
        app.set_app_menu(self.app_menu)

        self.add_simple_action(app,'quit',self.quit_cb)
        self.add_simple_action(app,'histo',self.histo_cb)
        self.add_simple_action(app,'about',self.about_cb)
        self.add_simple_action(app,'help',self.help_cb)
        # # Menu bar attached app
        self.menu_bar = self.add_menu_bar(app)
        #---création submenu1
        self.submenu1 = self.add_sub_menu('Miscellaneous',self.menu_bar)
        #---création de section 3
        section3 = self.add_section(self.submenu1)
        #---gestion des item
        self.add_menuitem(section3,'Help', 'app.help',"accel", GLib.Variant("s", "<Control>H"))
        self.add_menuitem(section3,'About', 'app.about')
        self.add_menuitem(section3,'Historic version', 'app.histo')

        #code writed here in order to debug
        submenu1 = self.add_sub_menu('Miscellaneous 1',self.menu_bar)
        # # add section to submenu
        section1 = self.add_section(submenu1)
        # add item to section
        self.add_simple_action(app,'pref',self.pref_cb)
        self.add_menuitem(section1,'Preference', 'app.pref',"accel", GLib.Variant("s", "<Control>P"))

    def on_app_activate(self, app):
        self.window.show_all()

    def on_app_shutdown(self, app):
        pass

    #here only in order to debug corresponding part and deleted after
    def pref_cb(self, action, data=None):
        print 'action preference not dev !!!!!!!!'
    # end block to be deleted
    def histo_cb(self, action, data=None):
        print 'historique des versions'
        print 'Version 1.30 add root class with basic menu '
        print '#Version 1.31 > a class inherit MyApp_root and try to add something'

    def about_cb(self, action, data=None):
        about = MyAbout(version=__version__)
        about.run()

    def help_cb(self, action, data=None):
        print "aide non developpe"

    def quit_cb(self, action, data=None):
        self.app.quit()

class MyAppNew(MyApp_root):
    """ inherit class MyApp_root """
    def __init__(self):
        MyApp_root.__init__(self);
        # # add submenu attached menu_bar
        submenu = self.add_sub_menu('Miscellaneous next',self.menubar) #error here AttributeError: 'MyAppNew' object has no attribute 'menubar'
        section1 = self.add_section(submenu)
        # add item to section
        self.add_menuitem(section1,'work hard', 'app.work')     
        self.add_simple_action(app,'work',self.work_cb)

    def run(self, argv):
        """ in order to run class """
        pass # ??????

    # here start to transfer all call back not necessary in root class
    def work_cb(self, action, data=None):
        print " It's very hard for me to make a class inherit class MyApp_root"

    # to adapt a new help
    def help_cb(self, action, data=None):
        print "How to implement polymorhisme in order to change action in th child class here ??"


if __name__ == '__main__':

    new_test = True
    if new_test:
        app = MyAppNew()
    else:
        application = MyApp_root()
        application.run(sys.argv)
```

Hello everybody, 
I know why error occur , self.menubar is not created in the init of root MyApp_root. But its created with  self.on_app_startup when event 'startup' occur.
during start running class. Ok it's said
but now who could help me and say me how I must operate to add some new submenu in MyAppNew. Thank a lot by advance

Comment: Hi nobody has a little idea!!!. I would like build appli in Two step. First step is basis and standard menu. In a second step I complete menu for a dedicated app.  This approch seems difficult. And other way it's to keep one step but I would like avoid it !!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to help. A example of inherit class Gtk.Application. It's running on my linux except bug unity on top menu ""Unknown Application Name"" appear instead of really name it's know.
it's just a modest contribution

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: ISO-8859-1 -*-
from gi.repository import GLib, Gtk, Gio
import sys

from gi.repository import  Gdk
from gi.repository.GdkPixbuf import Pixbuf, InterpType

class MyAbout(Gtk.AboutDialog):
    __gtype_name__ = 'MyAbout' # nom pour css
    def __init__(self,title='',version="1.0",\
                 authors=["Francis"],\
                 name="PyGObject Tutorial",\
                 comment="New tutorial on using Python with GTK+ 3",\
                 website="http://www.learngtk.org/",\
                 label="LearnGTK Website",\
                 filename=None,\
                 size_x=100, size_y=100):
        Gtk.AboutDialog.__init__(self)
        self.set_title(title)
        self.set_version(version)
        self.set_authors(authors)
        if filename is not None:
            file = filename
        else:
            file = "/home/francis/Documents/Python-linux/demo_gtk3/battery.png"
        try:
            pixbuf = Pixbuf.new_from_file_at_size(file,size_x, size_y)
            self.set_logo(pixbuf)
        except:
            self.set_name(name)
        self.set_comments(comment)
        self.set_website(website)
        self.set_website_label(label)

__version__ = "V1_30"

class MyApp_root(object):
    """ just a little app with few menu """
    def __init__(self):
        GLib.set_application_name('My App')
        self.app = Gtk.Application.new('org.example.test', 0)
        self.app.connect('startup', self.on_app_startup)
        self.app.connect('activate', self.on_app_activate)
        self.app.connect('shutdown', self.on_app_shutdown)

    def add_sub_menu(self,texte, menu):
        """ just add submenu to menu return need reference to sub_menu"""
        submenu = Gio.Menu()
        menu.append_submenu(texte, submenu)
        return submenu

    def add_menu_bar(self,app):
        """ just add function menubar app need refernce to app_menu"""
        menu_bar = Gio.Menu()
        app.set_menubar(menu_bar)
        return menu_bar

    def add_section(self,app):
        """ just add a section
        note between 2 sections there is a separator"""
        section = Gio.Menu()
        app.append_section(None, section)
        return  section

    def add_simple_action(self, app, name, callback):
        """ in order to create callback fonction linked menu"""
        action = Gio.SimpleAction.new(name, None)
        action.connect('activate', callback)
        app.add_action(action)

    def add_menuitem(self,section,text,link,attribut_type=None, attribut_value=None):
        """ just add a item with parameter """
        item = Gio.MenuItem.new(text,link)
        if attribut_type is not None:
            # example item.set_attribute_value("accel", GLib.Variant("s", "<Control>Q"))
            item.set_attribute_value(attribut_type, attribut_value)
        section.append_item(item)

    def run(self, argv):
        """ in order to run class """
        self.app.run(argv)

    def insert_custom_menu(self):
        """ in order to add custom menu later"""
        pass

    def insert_custom_submenu_first(self):
        """ in order to add something in the first submenu before Quit """
        ## current section is self.custom_section
        pass

    def insert_custom_submenu_last(self):
        """ in order to add something in the last submenu before Quit """
        ## current section is self.custom_section_last
        pass

    def on_app_startup(self, app):
        """ auto start app in window, set menu and call back
        standard design in python callback action  is action_cb"""
        self.window = Gtk.ApplicationWindow.new(app)
        self.window.set_default_size(640, 480)
        self.window.set_title('AppMenu Demo')
        app.add_window(self.window)
        # # add Appmenu to app 
        self.app_menu = Gio.Menu()
        # insert something in the first submenu in dedicated section
        self.custom_section = self.add_section(self.app_menu)

        self.insert_custom_submenu_first()
        # last section to quit action
        section_last = self.add_section(self.app_menu)
        self.add_menuitem(section_last,'Quit', 'app.quit',"accel", GLib.Variant("s", "<Control>Q"))

        # it's necessary to link app-menu to app after section definition if not, accelerator don't operate
        app.set_app_menu(self.app_menu)

        self.add_simple_action(app,'quit',self.quit_cb)
        self.add_simple_action(app,'histo',self.histo_cb)
        self.add_simple_action(app,'about',self.about_cb)
        self.add_simple_action(app,'help',self.help_cb)
        # # Menu bar attached app
        self.menu_bar = self.add_menu_bar(app)
        # planed if custum menu 
        self.insert_custom_menu()
        #---make submenu1
        self.submenu1 = self.add_sub_menu('Miscellaneous',self.menu_bar)
        #---make section 3
        section3 = self.add_section(self.submenu1)
        #---item management 
        self.add_menuitem(section3,'Help', 'app.help',"accel", GLib.Variant("s", "<Control>H"))
        self.add_menuitem(section3,'About', 'app.about')
        self.add_menuitem(section3,'Historic version', 'app.histo')
        ## last section dedicated to custom add in last submenu
        self.custom_section_last= self.add_section(self.submenu1)
        self.insert_custom_submenu_last()

    def on_app_activate(self, app):
        self.window.show_all()

    def on_app_shutdown(self, app):
        pass

    def histo_cb(self, action, data=None):
        print 'historique des versions'
        print 'Version 1.30 add root class with basic menu '
        print '#Version 1.31 > a class inherit MyApp_root and try to add something'

    def about_cb(self, action, data=None):
        """ about app"""
        about = MyAbout(version=__version__)
        about.run()

    def help_cb(self, action, data=None):
        """ in order to help user """
        print "aide non developpe"

    def quit_cb(self, action, data=None):
        self.app.quit()

class MyAppNew(MyApp_root):
    """ inherit class MyApp_root """
    def __init__(self):
        MyApp_root.__init__(self);

    def run(self, argv):
        """ in order to run class """
        self.app.run(argv)

    def insert_custom_submenu_first(self):
        """ in order to add something in the first submenu before Quit """
        ## current section is self.custom_section
        self.add_menuitem(self.custom_section,'something 1', 'app.work1')     
        self.add_simple_action(self.app,'work1',self.work1_cb)

    def insert_custom_menu(self):
        """ custom menu in child class"""
        submenu1 = self.add_sub_menu('Miscellaneous next',self.menu_bar)
        # # add section to submenu
        section1 = self.add_section(submenu1)
        # add item to section
        self.add_menuitem(section1,'work hard', 'app.work')     
        self.add_simple_action(self.app,'work',self.work_cb)

    def insert_custom_submenu_last(self):
        """ in order to add something in the last submenu before Quit """
        ## current section is self.custom_section_last
        self.add_menuitem(self.custom_section_last,'something in the last submenu', 'app.work2')     
        self.add_simple_action(self.app,'work2',self.work2_cb)

    def work_cb(self, action, data=None):
        print " It's very hard for me to make a class inherit class MyApp_root"

    def work1_cb(self, action, data=None):
        print " something 1"

    def work2_cb(self, action, data=None):
        print " ready to do  something in the last submenu"
    # to adapt a new help
    def help_cb(self, action, data=None):
        print "How to implement overwrite method in order to change action in child class here"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MyAppNew()
    app.run(sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case assuming you really want to work like this the solution is to make sure that you add the new submenu after `self.menu_bar` is created.

In your case the easiest way to do this is adding a function like `self.insert_custom_menu` (or something like that) in `MyApp_root` which you will overwrite in `MyAppNew`. If you then have a function call to this function in `on_app_startup` it will be easy to add the new menu options

So for example in `MyApp_root` the function will be like this:

```
def insert_custom_menu(self):
    pass
```

While in `MyAppNew` the function will be like this:

```
def insert_custom_menu(self):
    submenu = self.add_sub_menu('Miscellaneous next',self.menubar)
    section1 = self.add_section(submenu)
    self.add_menuitem(section1,'work hard', 'app.work')
```

The reason why this will work is that `MyAppNew` does not try to add something to a menu during `init` while the menu is only create after the `startup` signal. With the above solution the custom part of the menu is also loaded after `startup` which resolves the issue at hand.

Comment: Thank you very much . The idea is so obvious now !!  In fact , we must go through reasoning. If I plan to add menus , I foresee exactly the place where I want to add it with a empty method that will be overwrited by inheritance. I can even provide several entry point. it's super awesome, I 'm back 3 replies to a question.

Comment: Long life to stackoverflow members's

Comment: You're welcome. Since you're new here, please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work